# cxGrid uppercase letters only

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

Is there a way to have cxGrid (devexpress)  accept only uppercase letters ? Or have it accept uppercase only for certain fields ? I could not find any setting in the grid that would achieve this...

Comment: As a side note: even [devexpress] have a tag icon, why [delphi] still doesnt?

Comment: Because somebody paid money to sponsor the devexpress tag, @user539484, and nobody has done the same for the delphi tag. Perhaps Embarcadero has not deemed it necessary to advertise that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `Column.Properties` to `TextEdit` and then

```
Column.Properties.CharCase = ecUpperCase
```